# Cybersource - how to set value of sendToProduction

Tags: configuration, payment-gateway

I have an issue with our test implementation of CyberSource, that we need to use to do some testing, and it looks like I need to set the value of 'sendToProduction' to reflect a value that we should use for test purposes.  How would I change that value?

Comment: Hi !!Chris is cyber source provide after placing order it will be redirect on cyber source and pay there?

Answer (score 0):

This will be in a web.config or app.config somewhere.  This from CyberSource may be useful:

http://support.cybersource.com/cybskb/index?page=content&id=C100&pmv=print&impressions=false

especially this point:

---

1. By default, you will be in the test mode when you initially configure your settings. When you are ready to process orders from your customers, you need to manually change the value of sendtoproduction to either True or 1, depending on your API client. To determine what the correct value for sendtoproduction is, please refer to the documentation for your API.